# How to add item in Arraylist<Model> android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

How to add item in Arraylist android

I have Model (Not have Constructor, have setter and getter)

```
private int user_id;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String pic;
```

and my code

```
List<MeModel> meModels = new ArrayList<>();

meModels.clear();
meModels.get(0).setFirstname("Hello");
meModels.get(0).setLastname("World");
```

it's not working.

How to add this, thanks!

Comment: where is `meModels.add(new MeModel(...))` and `clear` delete everything from list

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh ohhhh ,thanks!!!! I forget it!

Comment: Why you are doing clear the list? How is it possible to get data from the list after clearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After applying [`List#clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear()) will empty your list so you will no longer have the access to any item

```
List<MeModel> meModels = new ArrayList<>();

meModels.clear();
meModels.add(new MeModel(...));
// ^^^^^ add item
meModels.get(0).setFirstname("Hello"); // get item
meModels.get(0).setLastname("World");
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help , don't worry and you don't have to comment about yourself , sometime it happens, happy coding

Answer (score 2):

It must be returns `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Because there is no item in the list. Why don't you create a constructor for your model? If I were you, I would create a constructor and do something like this:

```
Model model = new Model();
model.setBlahBlah(..);
meModels.add(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pavneet_Singh you must first add an item and then you can accesss it. Like this

```
List<MeModel> meModels = new ArrayList<>();
meModels.clear();
meModels.add(new MeModel());
meModels.get(0).setFirstname("Hello");
meModels.get(0).setLastname("World");
```

Anyhow a more performant approach is to costruct first the object and then to add it to the `ArrayList`, like this:

```
List<MeModel> meModels = new ArrayList<>();
meModels.clear();
MeModel meMod = new MeModel()
meMod.setFirstname("Hello");
meMod.setLastname("World");
meModels.add(meMod);
```

This because as you can see by this way you save a call for each row, that is `get(0)`. It may seems a stupid thing, but in a big iteration or on an old and less powerful device it could be important

Answer (score 0):

After clearing data how can you access that object.
First add object using add() method then you can access those models